# add "floating" TextView

Tags: android, textview

I would like to add a moving "floating" text to a working application.

I have a working application with some basic layout, which is something like:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView />
    <TextView /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

My app adds TextViews dynamically, so I need the scrollview...

I would like to have a small indication, like a "+1" appear every time a user clicks somewhere, and than float (move) upwards and disappear at the top of the screen.
I would be thankful to anyone who can offer a simple way to do it.

- Should I create a `TextView` dynamically, and add it to the layout?
- Do I need to add a relative layout overlapping the ScrollView so I can move the text relative to it?
- should I try and draw it on a canvas that I creat?
- should I use an `ObjectAnimator` and just make it all "animated"?

I don't have prior experience with any of those so I hope someone can point me to the simplest route to take before I try all of these...

### Update:

I was able to create a "hovering" Text view in a specific position (no movement yet):

- Added a RelativeLayout as root layout to my previous layout.
- I created a layout for the floating text:

  ```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/floatingViewLinearLayout" >
    <TextView />
  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- Created a costume View to handle it:

public class FloatingText extends View {

```
private View floatingLayoutView;

public FloatingText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    floatingLayoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.floating_text, null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) floatingLayoutView
            .findViewById(R.id.flaotingViewTextView);
    tv.setText("+1");
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    tv.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    tv.bringToFront();
 }
 public View getFloatingLayoutView() {
    return floatingLayoutView;
 }
```

}

Note that I've add a get method to receive the view. I'm sure this is a horrible solution. Next you can see how I used it:

- add this code in the onResume of the main activity:

  ```
  RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainRelativeLayout);
  FloatingText ft = new FloatingText(this);
  final View floatingLayoutView = ft.getFloatingLayoutView();
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
          new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  lp.setMargins(140, 300, 0, 0);
  floatingLayoutView.setLayoutParams(lp);

  main.addView(floatingLayoutView);
  ```

I would like the be able to let the FloatingText class do the addView itself, but I'm still not sure about a clean way of doing it.

The next challenge is to animate it in a way compatible with API 8. Seems like the Animation helpers were added in API 11 and some (like the viewproperyanimator that amAlsoNew mentioned) were added in API 12.

Again, any pointers and iseas would be very welcomed!

Comment: have you thought about using `Toast` messages?

Comment: I did, but Toast just appears and disappears and I would like to be able to control it a bit more. (floating upwards, for example)

Comment: I've just saw several recomendations for the nineoldandroids library http://nineoldandroids.com/ so I'll give it a try. So if you have any generic comment, even for higher APIs I'll be greatfull...

Answer (score 2):

**Normal Translate Animation** or **ObjectAnimator** or **Viewproperty animator** can be used for this purpose (**Note**: ObjectAnimator /Viewproperty animator is not available below **android version 3** ).

Suppose your view is at the bottom of the screen & height of the screen is 512px; you can perform translate UP animation by (with animation listener):

```
view.animate().translationYBy(-512).setListener(new AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            // after animation set visibility gone
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `ViewPropertyAnimator` should be good. Can you elaborate on how to use with a working application? I've read some docs and saw some samples, but my main question is how to make the View "float" above other elements in my layout. Add a frame? get a canvas somehow?

Comment: Editing my answer with viewproperyanimator eg;-

Comment: Thanks for the additional code. I'm afraid the ViewPropertyAnimator was added in API 12, so I'll keep looking for another solution.